# SVG base64 encoded in CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, base64

I created a logo that I'll be using on a site in AI and used an SVG Optimizer to output an optimized file. Initially I embedded the svg file into the HTML but seeing as it's a fixed logo across all pages I thought it would be best to remove it from the HTML and insert in my CSS as a background image. When I insert the base64 encoded link my link wraps line after line, maybe 15 lines, which just seems much too long.

Below is a clip of what I have. I obviously cut the remaining 14 or so lines. My questions is: Is there a way to shorten the actual link for this without using js? Similar to a relative path but for an encoded URI.

```
#logo { background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4NCjwhLS0gR2VuZXJhdG9yOiBBZG9iZSBJb...); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can add carriage returns and spaces and it will still work. [Here's an example from the SVG test suite](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/Test/20061213/svggen/filters-blend-01-b.svg)

```
    <image x="40" y="5" width="100" height="98" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAAABCAMAAAAfBfuPAAAABGdBTUEAAK/INwWK6QAAABl0RVh0
     U29mdHdhcmUAQWRvYmUgSW1hZ2VSZWFkeXHJZTwAAAEsUExURfb/AK3/AAD/9/9sAIn/AN7/ABT/
     AAB//zD/AP9GAAD/s1H/AAD/H/8AxwD/bn8A/1wA/wD/XJv/AP8Ai//MAGP/ABMA/wD/LP8A6P8K
     AP8AF/8A9QD/xAAA/wD1/9MA/wD/gABY/wD/Cf8ATJEA//+6AACT/wCn/+v/AAD/TAD/kf8AYKMA
     //8kAAAk/wAV/y0A/3b/AP80AAD/O/cA//8A/wD///8An/8A2QD/Ev8AAMQA/+0A/7MA////AP8A
     CuAA//8AJ24A/0sA//8AOAA0/wAK/wBF//8WAAgA/x8A///2AL//AP8AdTwA/wn/AP/bAP+AAP+U
     AM//AP+nAP8AtADp/wD/o0D/AP/qAADb/wC5/wDL/wD/AAD/7QD/0gD/4CH/AABr//9ZAG2IeB4A
     AABvSURBVHjaYrCyl3J0Udb2FTYP5bWQkDY1sXGQt7bVUeF3EnD2M/AS85R109dzdVdMYldTj46J
     CpMzY4pLiJfhCtdS4BPUNBbnsVSK9WdL5IjgFjVkEWL0CWbVYLDzjgwQUQ0JCmRO5jTS9ZAECDAA
     3aQTV3E5iioAAAAASUVORK5CYII="/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Robert I guess what I meant was if there is a way to shorten the URI in the css similar to how you would if you were getting an img with the path directory but without the path directory (if that makes sense). For instance if I were getting an img from my server I would use mysite.com/imgs/img1.jpg or ../imgs/img1.jpg - however, since I am using encoded base64 svg would I be able to use or output something like url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94b..)

Comment: The data is the data, there's not much you can do other than put it in an external file instead of a data url.